# Icons path altered in built editor

Tags: ckeditor

I've made a couple plugins for ckeditor and added icons for them. These icons show up when I embed the unbuilt code on a test page, but, when I build the editor, the minimized code thinks the icons at 'original/path/to/the/icon.png?t=D5AK' instead of 'original/path/to/the/icon.png'. This error does not occur when I copy an icon from another plugin in the src code. At the moment the only way I am adding the icon is through "icon: this.path + 'icons/icon.png'," in plugin.js. Is there somewhere I need to add a reference to the icon?

Answer (score 0):

This is an intentional addition to resources' paths. It ensures that every two CKEditor releases have different paths to the same resource what disables cache. And this works perfectly unless you're trying to load CKEditor from local file system than from a web server.